# Google Maps unexpected padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a google maps in my web application, can be seen in image:
[Google Maps padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukB4z.png).

The design is based on bootstrap sb-admin (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/).

The problem is the unexpected padding of the map, marked left & right on image. I want the google map to be aligned with te 3 boxes above (the ones with 'View Details'), just like the table left of the google maps below the first box above.

When I look into the details of the google maps, I notice that not the general div is forcing the padding, but a child div (see image for details).

Any suggestions on how I can fix this or point out in which direction I should search?

Comment: can you post a link for tour project or an image?

Comment: Can't the image be seen in the link 'Google Maps paddin' in the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't fix it with 'proper' css, but encapsulating the maps div in an other div fixed it for me:

`<div class="row" >
       <div class="col-lg-3" id="events"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-9">
           <div id="map"></div>
       </div>
   </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
!important
```

Next to your padding css. This should override any css that google is adding. Also use inspect element on chrome to identify what is creating the padding and apply the style to that!

Comment: Yeah, somehow I could not fix it with !important. The div marked with mouse-over is the one that was 'pushing' the padding.
I found an other fix thought: I encapsulated the maps div in an other div
`<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="events"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>`
this fixed it.

Comment: Not totally related, but just as a recomendation, use col-md- for bootstrap when developing for desktop. Just seems to react better when looking at the mobile version